# Permutation At A Railway Track

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, catalan-numbers

[image: Switching Network]

Engines numbered 1, 2, ..., n are on the line at the left, and it is desired to rearrange(permute) the cars as they leave on the right-hand track. An engine that is on the spur track can be left there or sent on its way down the right track, but it can never be sent back to the incoming track. For example if n = 3, and we ha the engines numbered 1,2,3 on the left track, then 3 first goes to the spur track. We could then send 2 to the spur, then on the way to its right,then send 3 on the way, then 1, obtaining the new order 1,3,2.
We have to find all the possible permutations for specific n.

For n=1, answer = 1;

For n=2  answer = 2;

For n=3  answer = 5;

Didn't find any generality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can ignore the straight track; sending a car through it is equivalent to putting it onto the spur and taking it out immediately. (At least if you don't care about which orientation the cars end up in).

Thus, a plan for what you do will be some mixture of $n$ "put a car into the spur" operations and $n$ "take a car out from the spur" operations. Two different sequence of operations will always lead to different permutations (why?), and a sequence of operation is valid if no prefix of it has more "take out from spur" operations in it than it has "put into spur" operations.

This means that every valid operation sequence corresponds uniquely to a *string of matching parentheses* of length $2n$, and the number of such strings is the [Catalan number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number) $C_n=\frac1{n+1}\binom{2n}n$.

Comment: let me read catalan number first

Comment: That is one classy solution.

Comment: please explain it in a detailed way. The 2nd and 3rd paragraph

Comment: @Kishan: What confuses you about those paragraphs?

Comment: Two different sequence of operations will always lead to different permutations (why?), and a sequence of operation is valid if no prefix of it has more "take out from spur" operations in it than it has "put into spur" operations.

Comment: and the 3rd para commpletely.

Comment: Example: If the cars are lined up $1234$ going into the spur, we could put 4 on the spur, put 3 in, take 3 out, take 4 out of the spur, put 2 in, put 1 in, take 1 out, take 2 out. This would correspond to the parenthesis ((1)2)((3)4). A right parenthesis, to the right of a number is "put car in" and the matching left parenthesis corresponds to taking that car out later.

Comment: @KishanKumar: (1) If you have two different sequences of operations, then consider what happens at the _first_ difference between them. At that point, say car $a$ is next to enter the spur, and car $b$ is at the front of the spur. If your next operation is "out", then $b$ will come before $a$ in the final permutation; it the next operation is "in", then $a$ is now in front of $b$ on the spur and must come before $b$ in the final permutation. Therefore different sequences cannot lead to teh same permutation.

Comment: @KishanKumar: (2) If a sequence has a prefix with more "out" operations than "in", that means that the sequence will at some point ask you to take a car out of the spur when the spur is empty. That is of course not possible. On the other hand, it should be clear that this is the _only_ thing that can prevent a sequence from being executable.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Thanks for explaining. But hw this leads to catalan numbers. I checked matching parentheses,which also leads to catalan numbers, then the triangles out of a polygon.

Comment: @pjs36 last comment for you too

Comment: @KishanKumar: Do you agree that the valid sequences of "in" and "out" are exactly those that are strings of matching parentheses? It is a well-known property (and possible definition) of Catalan numbers that they count strings of matching parentheses.

Comment: @HenningMakholm this can be realted with matching parentheses which give rise to catalan numbers. So i am fully satisfied by your answer. and http://www.maths.usyd.edu.au/u/kooc/catalan/cat11rail.pdf also helped me a lot https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m9Khxn2g-6w and this too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23616/discussion-between-kishan-kumar-and-henning-makholm).